# In a situation of just one person in one test, is it grammatically correct to use the plural form of "results"?

Tags: grammar

A [tutorial gives](https://youtu.be/NLLKSHJfrvU?list=PLOSo0A8ngEXUNqNesQ6cFtmtsL95UZWYh&t=18) a sentence

[image]

> will I get
>   better **results** for my IELTS essay if I
>   have interesting ideas

which uses the plural form of "results". However, there is only one essay task in an IELTS test.

Is that grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

According to the Oxford Dictionary

> **[result](https://www.lexico.com/definition/result)** 
>  1.3. A final score, mark, or placing in a sporting event or
>   examination.
>  ‘exam **results**’
>   *A panel of choreographers, artistic directors, and former dancers tallies **these results into a final score**.*

Check the example that I have quoted: they tally **results** into a final score.
Consider that your essay is evaluated from different points of view, different characteristics (plural) are checked - grammar, syntax, ... -, obtaining each of them **a result**. You receive multiple **results** from one essay and all **results** obtained are summarized in a final score.